# Redefining formatting commands to add colors

Tags: macros, color

I'm writing a document, and I'd like for all bold text to be red.  I was wondering how I could `renewcommand` the `textbf` command so that it would be wrapped in `\textcolor{red}`?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please note that instead of redefining the "bold" command it would often be more appropriate to define a new *semantic* command with a speaking name about what you actually want to express with your bold red text, and use this instead of `\textbf`.

Comment: Paulo: The LaTeX is generated from an org-mode file, which is why I want to inject new behavior into `\textbf` rather than use a new command (which is what I would do if I wrote the LaTeX directly).

Comment: It may be wothwhile to add a feature request to org-mode developers to generate semantic markup, say `\important{...}`.

Comment: Aditya: I agree.

Comment: @gnuvince Yes, in this case it is a "valid" usecase – I just wanted to add this note for the general case. (Also, please note that when you add an @ to the user name, I get a notification about your comment.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default definition of `textbf` is

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}
```

To add a new feature you can simple add `\color{red}`

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries\color{red}}
```

`\DeclareTextFontCommand` overrides the original definition without errors. You only get an info by `\@latex@info`

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries\color{red}}
\begin{document}
text \textbf{foo} bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing the mandatory "don't do it" recommendation. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: You did it now ;-)